# Casting parameter to decimal type without rounding

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server column of type `numeric(38,8)`. I'm passing a decimal value '11.25' as a parameter and inserting into the db like this within my stored procedure:

```
PaymentTotal = CAST(@PaymentTotal AS DECIMAL(38,8))
```

The data is being inserting into the db as 11.00000000

I can't understand why this wouldn't be 11.25000000 ?

I have tried `(10,2)` and a combination of others, I've tried casting as `float` and `int` but nothing seems to prevent the rounding.

Comment: What is the type of `@PaymentTotal` variable

Comment: It is type decimal.

Comment: just `decimal` ? what is the precision & scale ? If you didn't specify any, it is defaulted with scale 0

Comment: Yes. I didn't realize I had to set the precision & scale on the application side. I was simply converting the value to a decimal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
DECLARE @PaymentTotal DECIMAL = 12.5

SELECT CAST(@PaymentTotal AS DECIMAL(38,8))
```

The above code will return `12.00000000`

You have to specify the precision of your variable's type like this:

```sql
DECLARE @PaymentTotal DECIMAL(38,8) = 12.5


SELECT CAST(@PaymentTotal AS DECIMAL(38,8))
```

and the above code will return `12.50000000`

Comment: Thank you. But why can't I pass the value as a float from the application side and convert it on the DB side?

Comment: float is approximate datatype and value will be lost in the application side, before being passed to db side